# Why does contains selector only work with .length?

Tags: jquery

Two cases one works other does not and I wonder why? As this is not transparent for me it really makes me wonder.

Hides the myform:

```
if($("#msg:contains('Registration successful')").length ) {$("#myform").hide();}
```

Doesn't work as expected (always hides the myform):

```
if($("#msg:contains('Registration successful')") ) {$("#myform").hide();}
```

Why is `.length` required here?

Comment: Because an empty array `[]` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Short answer: `[] == true` is true

Comment: I don't see how first example gets to be empty? It has :contains selector, doesn't this check if anything is in the #msg div?

Answer (score 1):

The .length *counts* how many DOM objects (i.e. HTML tags) were returned.

Without the .length the javascript just checks if *anything* at all was returned, and the way jQuery works is that a blank result is still a valid jQuery object. (For example you can chain commands on that object.)

Comment: isn't .length only used to count characters of a string?

Comment: `.length` on a jQuery object returns the number of elements that matched your selector.

Comment: @LazyPeon No, on a string it counts characters, but on `array` it counts elements, and on jQuery it counts matches.

Comment: so you are saying that if I have another string that matches the same number of characters as "Registration successful" it will also evaluate to TRUE? Ho do I check if #myform contains specific string then?

Comment: @LazyPeon jQeury is not returning a string, it is returning a jQuery object.

Comment: can I check if a specific div element contains specific string?

Comment: @LazyPeon I don't understand your question - isn't that what you are doing?

Comment: yes but I understand that .length only checks for number of elements on that string, if I have a string with the same number of elements  it would also return true

Comment: @LazyPeon It doesn't have anything to do with the string. The string you put in find a `DIV` element, and it counts how many `DIV`elements it found.

Answer (score 0):

Because only

```
if($("#msg:contains('Registration successful')").length )
```

results to be `true`. If condition must have a `true` in it to execute. Otherwise, a simple `object Object` won't execute the block.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `[]` (an empty jQuery object) evaluates to `true` and enters the body of the `if` block.

In the second example, `0` evaluates to `false` and does not enter the `if` block. Any value greater than `0` will be `true` (i.e. your selector matched something)

For example:

```
if([]){/*Enters this block*/}
if(0) {/*Does not enter this block*/}
if(99){/*Enters this block*/}
```

Comment: but why is the first example array and second integer?

Comment: Because `.length` returns a number referring to the number of elements that matched your jQuery selector. Since there are no elements that match, the length is 0. In the above case, since your jQuery selector is empty, it is equivalent to `[]`. Try it out in your browser console to illustrate the idea.